# Ubuntu (Dual Boots alongside Windows): Wifi fine, but Browsers Won't Stay Connected

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

This is my first post here. Please bear with me: I'm entirely new to Ubuntu, and to coding in general.

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on my Lenovo IdeaCentre AIO 510.
My Wifi appears to be connected just fine. Prior to my experiences with Ubuntu, my connection is generally excellent and I've never run into any issues in Windows. However, I have Firefox and Chrome browsers in Ubuntu, and both very frequently stop connecting to the internet. Sometimes only for several seconds, and up to about 10 minutes at a time. It will then reconnect, and often disconnect again some minutes later.

I know there are quite a few questions similar to mine out there, however I've tried several of the recommended solutions and can't seem to get anything to work for me. For what it was worth, I thought I'd post in a separate question.

Let me know what information I can provide for you. I'll start with the following:

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 00
   serial: 78:45:61:c0:27:19
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.8.0-56-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea03fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 0c
   serial: fc:45:96:26:79:de
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:33 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe900000-fe900fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff
```

Output of `iwconfig`:

```
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"suddenlink.net-E190"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 68:B6:FC:D3:E1:98   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1576
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1577
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 98e4 (rev c9)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15b3
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1578
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157d
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157a
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 4b)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4b)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller (rev 01)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b5
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 
802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: which kernel do you have and do you bootUEFI secure boot? there is an alternative driver that works excellent with the realtek cards but kernels newer than 4.4 prevent loading unsinged kernel modules when secure boot is on

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/931253/how-do-i-set-up-wifi-on-ubuntu-16-04-it-worked-fine-on-windows-and-now-that-iv/931259#931259. if you have secure boot  first try switching antennas, because you will have to turn off secure boot to use third party drivers.