# How do I set up WiFi on Ubuntu 16.04? It worked fine on Windows and now that I've switched I'm having extremely slow speeds and frequent disconnects

Tags: wireless

I have tried multiple options to fix this through online searches but nothing has worked. I'm new to Linux so it is entirely possible that there's just something I'm screwing up along the way. Also wondering if my laptop just doesnt like Ubuntu. I dont know, but it's very frustrating and i would prefer to not switch back to Windows. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61454/discussion-on-question-by-sabo-how-do-i-set-up-wifi-on-ubuntu-16-04-it-worked-f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the default drivers in the repository don't work well. you need to install updated drivers.

first you need to be sure to have installed required software.
`sudo apt-get install git make dkms`

also be sure you have the headers for your kernel installed.
linux-headers-common linux-headers-amd64(if 64bit) kbuild and linux-compiler
they usually auto install each other

WARNING: kernels newer than 4.4 will refuse to load unsigned modules when secure boot is enabled.

next  get the drivers:
`git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new`

navigate to the folder just made 'rtlwifi_new'
`cd ~/rtlwifi_new`
 and type `make` then `sudo make install`

reboot and all should be working

Comment: It started working and now it's stuck saying: 0% [Waiting for headers]

Comment: can you get a wired connection? the wifi will stall until you get it fixed

Comment: Not really an option right now...Im going to try to get to a friends house or something today to try that out though.

Comment: those driver fixed my card. rtl8188ee. If you have time to wait it out, it will eventually download between disconnects

Comment: OK so i made some progress. Got past your first step.  Just curious, so I don't screw something up, how exactly do I make sure the headers are installed?

Comment: open the software center or aptitude. they are under the heading 'kernel'

Comment: Well my Wi-Fi is now completely gone. No option to turn it back on lol

Comment: a reboot is required for kernel modules

Comment: I did reboot and when it came back, no wifi.

Comment: `sudo apt-get uninstall firmware-realtek` then `sudo make install again` and reboot

Comment: *E: Unable to locate package firmware-realtek*

Comment: "E: Invalid operation uninstall"

Comment: sorry remove not uninstall. ok we need to find the package name that ubuntu's drivers are in

Comment: Yeah, I'm lost.

Comment: I would `cd ~/rtlwifi_new` then do a `sudo make uninstall` reboot and try chili555's answer especially if the laptop is an HP model

Comment: @Jeremy31  secure boot is preventing the modprobe

Comment: Secure boot prevents the modprobe of the compiled from git version, not the in-kernel version. He had weak wireless even with secure boot before that.

Comment: @the new module will fix the wireless...but an update to 4.4 and newer kernels prevents him from using it with secure boot on. it is actually the kernel not secure boot that is preventing the modprobe.  with kernels below 4.4 there is no issue with using the git module and secure boot on.

Comment: @Jeremy31 i have an HP, these drivers fixed my wifi. but I have kernel 3.18, and when I tested them wit 4.9 I had secure boot off, thus I didn't know of this new kernel restriction.

Comment: The 3.18 kernel is not supported.  Only 3.13, 4.4, 4.8 and 4.10 are currently supported.  The 4.4 kernel has the antenna select option.  Why not use dkms if this version is needed, then you do not need to reinstall after automatic kernel updates?

Answer (score 0):

Quite often, a weak signal and the resultant slow speeds is a symptom of the antenna wire being connected to connection #1 on the card when the default driver is expecting to see the signal at connection #2, or vice versa. Of course, you could open the laptop and switch the wire or you could try antenna selection at the driver level.

Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Is there any improvement?

If this is ineffective, please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
```